# How to make a for - if loop using datetime arrays in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime, for-loop, if-statement

I have a datetime array with sunrise hour (whole_set_sr), a datetime array with sunset hour (whole_set_ss), and a datetime array with lots with whole calendar data (tm_whole_date). All of them have the same number of elements, so position 1 should be tested against position 1, position 2 should be tested with position 2 and so on..

I am trying to create a binary array with the same number of elements, in which it returns 1 if the element in tm_whole_date is >= the sun rise hour (whole_set_sr) AND <= the sun set hour (whole_set_ss), and 0 if it is out of the these conditions.

I have attempted the following:

```
    date_list = [];
date_indexes = [];
numel(whole_date)

for i = 1:numel(tm_whole_date)
    if (tm_whole_date(i,1) >= whole_set_sr(i,1)) && tm_whole_date(i,1) <= whole_set_ss(i,1)
            bin_x = 1
    else
        bin_x = 0
    end

    date_list(i) = bin_x
end
```

It is giving me an array (date_list) full of zeros when there should be values meeting the condition and returning 1.

Also, I need to create a list with the indexes of the positions of 1 values in the whole set of datetime tm_whole_date . (to know based on indexes which elements meet the criteria).

I dont know what it going wrong here and I would appreciate very much some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brilliant thing about MATLAB is you can operate on entire arrays without looping.

```matlab
after_sunrise = tm_whole_date >= whole_set_sr;
before_sunset = tm_whole_date <= whole_set_ss;
date_list = after_sunrise & before_sunset;
```

should be all you need to get a logical array (array of true and false / 0 and 1)

Or in one line:

```matlab
date_list = tm_whole_date >= whole_set_sr  & tm_whole_date <= whole_set_ss;
```

Make sure that `whole_set_sr` and `whole_set_ss` actually contain the entire datetime though, because otherwise the `tm_whole_date >= whole_set_sr` and  `tm_whole_date <= whole_set_ss` comparisons won't yield what you expect.

The added bonus of this way over looping and appending to an array is that it's much *much* faster.

Once you've got your logical array, getting the indices that are true is as simple as using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

```matlab
date_indices = find(date_list);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem in a much easier way.